Error getting AppIntent from LNAction message how do I set a default value for intent?
Getting this error in my widget when trying to set configuration value, any ideas?
Error getting AppIntent from LNAction: AppIntent has missing parameter value for 'radius'. You may need to set a default value in the initializer of your @Parameter, or using the default method on your Query.
